# How do I count nodes in a B-tree?

Tags: c++, b-tree

I am struggling to count nodes in a B-tree. Here keys refer to an array of values and num_keys refers to the valid number of keys currently.  How do I approach this to make it work?

```
int BTree::count_nodes(shared_ptr<btree> root){
  int count = 0;
  int i =0;
  if (root == NULL) {
    return 0;
  } 
  for (i = 0; i < root->num_keys; i++) {
    count +=root->keys[i];
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you studied recursion yet?  Tree problems often leverage recursion to get an elegant solution.

Comment: @StephenNewell Don't use recursion by default. It's more elegant and more safe in my opinion to use a stack or a queue to execute DFS or BFS.

Comment: Please show your `btree` API. You want to recursively return one plus the sum of `count_nodes` of the children. You should probably take a `const btree&` as an argument.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Pretty safe to use recursion in a B-tree. The heights don't get large, and it doesn't get degenerate by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can iterate over all nodes in the tree, incrementing the counter each time.

```
int BTree::count_nodes(shared_ptr<btree> root) {
  int count = 0;
  std::stack<shared_ptr<btree> > traversal_stack;
  traversal_stack.push(root);

  while (!traversal_stack.empty()) {
    shared_ptr<btree> top = traversal_stack.top();
    traversal_stack.pop();

    ++count;

    for (shared_ptr<btree> child : top->children) {
      traversal_stack.push(child);
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

This uses depth-first search. To do breadth-first search, change the `std::stack` into an `std::queue` and use `.peek()` instead of `.top()`.

Note that it may be more efficient to have each node keep track of its subtree's number of nodes, and for the counts to be updated whenever nodes move around, instead of having a function like this.